# Xcode12 can't change document type icon for iOS and macOS

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I create app for iOS and macOS.

I set document types and icons on Xcode 11, but it doesn't be applied for iOS 14 and macOS Catalina.Also Xcode 12 seem delete setting view of document type icon.
If anyone know correct way to set document type icons, please let me know.

Xcode 11 setting window of document types:[Xcode 11 setting window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snzoJ.png)

Xcode 12 setting window of document types:[Xcode 12 setting window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w30u4.png)

Part of info.plist for document types:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>zip</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>Document-ZIP.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>filetype-zip-textonly</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>application/zip</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Zip Archive</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Alternate</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.zip-archive</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>rar</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>Document-RAR.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>filetype-rar-textonly</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>application/rar</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>RAR Archive</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Alternate</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.rarlab.rar-archive</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <array>
                    <string>rar</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>UTImportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
                <string>public.archive</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>RAR Archive</string>
            <key>UTTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>filetype-rar-textonly</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.rarlab.rar-archive</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <array>
                    <string>rar</string>
                </array>
                <key>public.mime-type</key>
                <array>
                    <string>application/x-rar</string>
                    <string>application/x-rar-compressed</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
            <string>Document-ZIP</string>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.pkware.zip-archive</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>ZIP Archive</string>
            <key>UTTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>filetype-zip-textonly</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>public.zip-archive</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <array>
                    <string>zip</string>
                </array>
                <key>public.mime-type</key>
                <array>
                    <string>application/zip</string>
                    <string>application/octet-stream</string>
                    <string>application/x-zip-compressed</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
            <string>Document-RAR</string>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
                <string>public.archive</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>RAR Archive</string>
            <key>UTTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>filetype-rar-textonly</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.rarlab.rar-archive</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <array>
                    <string>rar</string>
                </array>
                <key>public.mime-type</key>
                <array>
                    <string>application/x-rar</string>
                    <string>application/x-rar-compressed</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
...(continue plist)
```